# What RegEx string will find the last (rightmost) group of digits in a string?

Tags: c#, regex

Looking for a regex string that will let me find the rightmost (if any) group of digits embedded in a string.  We only care about contiguous digits. We don't care about sign, commas, decimals, etc.  Those, if found should simply be treated as non-digits just like a letter.

This is for replacement/incrementing purposes so we also need to grab everything before and after the detected number so we can reconstruct the string after incrementing the value so we need a tokenized regex.

Here's examples of what we are looking for:

- "abc123def456ghi" should identify the'456'
- "abc123def456ghi789jkl" should identify the'789'
- "abc123def" should identify the'123'
- "123ghi" should identify the'123'
- "abc123,456ghi" should identify the'456'
- "abc-654def" should identify the'654'
- "abcdef" shouldn't return any match

As an example of what we want, it would be something like starting with the name 'Item 4-1a', extracting out the '1' with everything before being the prefix and everything after being the suffix.  Then using that, we can generate the values 'Item 4-2a', 'Item 4-3a' and 'Item 4-4a' in a code loop.

Now If I were looking for the first set, this would be easy.  I'd just find the first contiguous block of 0 or more non-digits for the prefix, then the block of 1 or more contiguous digits for the number, then everything else to the end would be the suffix.

The issue I'm having is how to define the prefix as including all (if any) numbers except the last set.  Everything I try for the prefix keeps swallowing that last set, even when I've tried anchoring it to the end by basically reversing the above.

Comment: You can [split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split.aspx) using the regex provided by @Birei and update the second index before concatenating to get the desired result.

Comment: How can you split?  What if the string is a44b44c?  The prefix should be 'a44b' and if I'm going to get into too much manual manipulation, then that defeats using regex which already supports named tokens.

Comment: By split, I meant (Regex.Split)[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split.aspx], hence the hyperlink in the previous comment. Applying `Regex.Split()` with give 3 tokens for `a44b44c` viz. `a44b`, `44` and `c`.

Comment: Aaah!  Didn't know about that one.  That works great!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

How about:

```
^(.*?)(\d+)(\D*)$
```

then increment the second group and concat all 3.

**Explanation:**

```
^         : Begining of string
  (       : start of 1st capture group
    .*?   : any number of any char not greedy
  )       : end group
  (       : start of 2nd capture group
    \d+   : one or more digits
  )       : end group
  (       : start of 3rd capture group
    \D*   : any number of non digit char
  )       : end group
$         : end of string
```

The first capture group will match all characters until the first digit of last group of digits before the end of the string.

or if you can use named group

```
^(?<prefix>.*?)(?<number>\d+)(?<suffix>\D*)$
```

Comment: Depending upon where the last set of digits are, this is probably more efficient than mine. +1

Comment: Ok, this one works great... but I can't see how!  Can you please edit this to show the comments about what each is doing?  For instance, I'm stumped even in your first group... (.*?) ... as I thought the question mark and asterisk were mutually exclusive after a period, but obviously I'm wrong there.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! :)  The non-greedy thing was exactly what I needed!  You get the vote!  Thanks! :)

Comment: never seen before this kind of documenting a regex with _: comment_, good idea thanks

Answer (score 7):

Try next regex:

```
(\d+)(?!.*\d)
```

Explanation:

```
(\d+)           # One or more digits.
(?!.*\d)        # (zero-width) Negative look-ahead: Don't find any characters followed with a digit.
```

---

**EDIT (OFFTOPIC of the question):**: This answer is incorrect but this question has already been answered in other posts so to avoid delete this one I will use this same regex other way, for example in `Perl` could be used like this to get same result as in `C#` (increment last digit):

```
s/(\d+)(?!.*\d)/$1 + 1/e;
```

Comment: Not quite.  That does properly identify the number, but it still doesn't show how to tokenize the string to get the prefix and suffix as well which is what I'm mostly struggling with.  Can you help there?

Comment: @MarqueIV: You are right, not what you wanted, I missed the point, sorry. But now there are some correct answers which solves your problem just fine.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try little bit simpler version:

```
(\d+)[^\d]*$
```

Comment: those others don't eve work for me…  this does.  simplicity is a drug.

Comment: Here's a test that confirms this works as expected: http://regex101.com/r/hN8zG5/1

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```cs
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"
    # Grab last set of digits, prefix and suffix.
    ^               # Anchor to start of string.
    (.*)            # $1: Stuff before last set of digits.
    (?<!\d)         # Anchor start of last set of digits.
    (\d+)           # $2: Last set of one or more digits.
    (\D*)           # $3: Zero or more trailing non digits.
    $               # Anchor to end of string.
    ", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

Answer (score 1):

What about not using Regex. Here's code snippet (for console)

```
string[] myStringArray = new string[] { "abc123def456ghi", "abc123def456ghi789jkl", "abc123def", "123ghi", "abcdef","abc-654def" };

        char[] numberSet = new char[] { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };
        char[] filterSet = new char[] {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m',
                                        'n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','-'};
        foreach (string myString in myStringArray)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("your string - {0}",myString);
            int index1 = myString.LastIndexOfAny(numberSet);
            if (index1 == -1)
            Console.WriteLine("no number");
            else
            {
               string mySubString = myString.Substring(0,index1 + 1);
               string prefix = myString.Substring(index1 + 1);
               Console.WriteLine("prefix - {0}", prefix);
               int index2 = mySubString.LastIndexOfAny(filterSet);
               string suffix = myString.Substring(0, index2 + 1);
               Console.WriteLine("suffix - {0}",suffix);
               mySubString = mySubString.Substring(index2 + 1);
               Console.WriteLine("number - {0}",mySubString);
               Console.WriteLine("_________________");
            }
        }
        Console.Read();
```